# Give balance new value outside def

Tags: python

How do you get the new value of balance when exiting the loop? Now it just takes the original value and prints it.
I have also tried with balance += (balance + dep)

```
balance = 500
def main(balance):
    if balance <= 999999:
        intrest = 0.01
    if balance >= 1000000:
        intrest = 0.02
    menu = int(input('Press 1 for balance, 2 for deposit, 3 for withdrawal or 4 for interest return: '))
    if menu == 1:
        print(balance)
    elif menu == 2:
        dep = int(input('How much do you want to deposit? '))
        balance = (balance + dep)
        print('Your new balance is', balance)
        if balance <= 999999:
            intrest = 0.01
        if balance >= 1000000:
            intrest = 0.02
            print('Congratulations, your intrest just went up!')
    elif menu == 3:
        wit = int(input('How much do you want to withdraw? '))
        balance = (balance - wit)
        print('Your new balance is', balance)
        if balance <= 999999:
            intrest = 0.01
        print('Your intrest is now back to standard!')
    elif menu == 4:
        intrest_return = balance + (balance * intrest)
        print(intrest_return)
    while True:
        restart = str(input('Would you like to do more? Press y for yes or n for no: '))
        if restart == 'y':
            main(balance)
        else:
            break
main(balance)
print(balance)
```

Comment: You only have to put a return in your function with **return balance** and then asign it to the variable like **balance=main(balance)**

Comment: I made an answer with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `return` in your code and after that asign it to your variable. This would be your code:

```
balance = 500
def main(balance):
    if balance <= 999999:
        intrest = 0.01
    if balance >= 1000000:
        intrest = 0.02
    menu = int(input('Press 1 for balance, 2 for deposit, 3 for withdrawal or 4 for interest return: '))
    if menu == 1:
        print(balance)
    elif menu == 2:
        dep = int(input('How much do you want to deposit? '))
        balance = (balance + dep)
        print('Your new balance is', balance)
        if balance <= 999999:
            intrest = 0.01
        if balance >= 1000000:
            intrest = 0.02
            print('Congratulations, your intrest just went up!')
    elif menu == 3:
        wit = int(input('How much do you want to withdraw? '))
        balance = (balance - wit)
        print('Your new balance is', balance)
        if balance <= 999999:
            intrest = 0.01
        print('Your intrest is now back to standard!')
    elif menu == 4:
        intrest_return = balance + (balance * intrest)
        print(intrest_return)
    while True:
        restart = str(input('Would you like to do more? Press y for yes or n for no: '))
        if restart == 'y':
            main(balance)
        else:
            break
    return balance
balance=main(balance)
print(balance)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `global balance` in the first line of your function.

Unless you do, any variable assigned inside a function is considered local, that's why you get the errors.